# How to play movies stored on my computer streamed to Android

Tags: wireless-networking, router, android, video-streaming

I've got some nice series downloaded and stored in a folder on my computer. Then, I jump into the bath and want to watch them on my Xperia. Both are connected to the same home network via my Belkin router.

I've never done that before, so I don't really know how to approach it. When I googled the best I could I came up with apps like [this one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nityaalabs.airstream&hl=en) but I don't really understand how to **serve** the media to the app or at least to the router.

Belkin has its own app for that but it seems that the media needs to be connected to the router and stored on an USB device...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

- Install airstream in your mobile
- Install airstream pc suite in your computer from the link
  http://airstream.io/download/
- Register with airstream in your mobile and login in to your mobile
  and pc with same credential
- Add the folders and file in pc suite and you can view the same under
  the Drive tab in your mobile
- AirStream-Suite should be allowed in pc firewall settings and router
  firewall settings
- Once it is done you can view and files in your mobile device.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried Gmote and followed more or less the same steps. The video plays all right **but** when I try to jump 18 minutes in the movie or so, it doesn't play. I've tried two different players - same problem. So I assumed that there's something else that needs to be done...

Comment: Not sure whether they have handled to pick the video at any mid point along the path.

Comment: Did anybody, as far you're informed?